# Prohibit manual build on specific branch in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I wonder if there is any way to prevent manually triggered builds on Master branch in Jenkins. I am using pipelines.

Ideally I would like to allow only a few people or no one (except admins) to manually trigger a build in master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prohibit builds  on the Job Configuration, use Enable Project-based Security.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Standard+Security+Setup